# How do I get the entity ID when inserting a new node?

Tags: 8, entities, hooks

How do I get the ID of the inserted entity?

I am trying to use `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave()` and `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert()`, but in neither of those I can get the entity ID.

In `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave()`, I used the following code.

```
 if ($entity->isNew()) {
    print $entity->id();
 }
```

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/188667/how-can-i-alter-the-title-of-a-node-upon-save? If not, can you provide more details?

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: Why not use Pathauto?

Comment: Please don't change a question to ask something else once it's been answered. If you have another question, just ask a new question

Comment: im having same issue.. did u fix it ?

Answer (score 6):

The ID isn't available in `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave()` (*pre* meaning *before*, as in not saved so the database hasn't assigned it an ID yet), but is definitely available in `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert()`.

This will work, for example:

```
function MODULE_node_insert(NodeInterface $node) {
  // No need to check `isNew()`; if it's in an insert hook, it's new.
  $nid = $node->id();
}
```

Comment: This hook is not working in my module. Unable to found the issue. Even I put die() as well.   
function hook_node_insert(NodeInterface $node) {
   print $nid = $node->id(); die('---------------');
}

Comment: You've spelled it wrong then, or not enabled the module, something other than what the docs say to do. This definitely answers your question _How to get nid while inserting new node drupal 8_. Look at the example for the hook itself: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert/8.2.x. It uses `$entity->id()`. I know from experience that those docs are correct

Comment: ok, need to do more debugging then. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Don't use `die`. Use a debugger like xdebug.

Comment: this hook is not triggered for me.. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do something similar - this worked for me:

```
function your_module_node_insert($node) {
  if ($node->getType() == 'your_node') {
        $node->setTitle('New entity ' . $node->id()); // to update title with node id
        $node->field_test = 'Id' . $node->id();  // or, to update a text field with node id
        $node->save();
  }
}
```